# Zend Studio 10 and PHPUnit from Composer

Tags: php, ide, phpunit, zend-studio

I have a project that uses [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) to manage it's dependencies; one of them being PHPUnit.

To run my project's test suite, I run the following command on the terminal:

```
bin/phpunit -c tests/
```

Using the binary from the Composer PHPUnit version and setting the configuration file to be loaded from the `tests/` directory.

It runs perfectly.

With Zend Studio 10 (BETA), though, I can't configure my project to run the tests the same way but inside the IDE.

Is there anyway to do that?